# Reading of a long file with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have to read a file with around 2.000.000 lines, that is composed as following:

N+1 lines

N lines (each with 3 colums)

N lines (each with 3 colums)

and this is repeated for 20 times in the same way.

I used np.genfromtxt but it takes too much time to load all the data into my arrays. Is there a faster method to do it?
This is my code:

````
import numpy as np
fopen = open(filename)
N=Npart
Nd=3

nlines = len(fopen.readlines())
nlines_in_snap = (3+3*N)
Nsnap = int(nlines/nlines_in_snap)

p = np.empty([Nsnap,N,Nd])
v = np.empty([Nsnap,N,Nd])
t = np.empty([Nsnap])

for i in range(Nsnap):
    for j in range(N):        
        initial_line = (i)*nlines_in_snap
    
        t[i] = np.genfromtxt(filename,skiprows=initial_line+2,max_rows=1)      
        p[i] = np.genfromtxt(filename,skiprows=initial_line+(3+N),max_rows=N) 
        v[i] = np.genfromtxt(filename,skiprows=initial_line+(3+2*N),max_rows=N) ```

Thank you!
````

Comment: Repeatedly opening the file and skipping forward is taking too much time.  You/we need to open the file once and feed blocks of lines to `genfromtxt` (or parse the 1 line block directly).  Use regular python file reading for a start.

Comment: Ok thanks, the problem Is that I have to repeat the same for the Number of snapshots (as in the code). Thus, maybe It Is more useful to use opentxt from Numpy?

Comment: `genfromtxt` works with an opened file, or with a list of strings (lines).  Basically anthing that can feed it lines.  I often demonstrate `genfromtxt` with a copy-n-paste text split into lines.

Answer (score 0):

I had a program that had to read 280k lines per minute the best way I found was by throwing the whole thing in a pandas database and just going from there

Comment: While pandas read_csv can be fast, I don't think it will handle this file.  It doesn't sound like all rows have the same number of columns.

Comment: Yes Indeed. I Need to open my file once instead of at each iteration, maybe putting that line outside the cycle

Answer (score 0):

One of the larger test files in my directory is:

```
In [87]: ll float.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 2500000 Sep  8  2018 float.csv
```

With a single read:

```
In [88]: data = np.genfromtxt('float.csv')
In [89]: data.shape
Out[89]: (1000, 100)
```

I can also read it in chunks:

```
In [90]: alist = []
    ...: with open('float.csv') as f:
    ...:     for i in range(10):
    ...:         tmp = np.genfromtxt(f, max_rows=100)
    ...:         alist.append(tmp)
    ...: 
In [91]: len(alist)
Out[91]: 10
In [92]: data1 = np.vstack(alist)
In [93]: np.allclose(data,data1)
Out[93]: True
```

I could also have done a `f.readlines` or other file read to get a block of lines.  But this shows that `genfromtxt` reads the `max_rows` and stops, leaving the file at the suitable point for the next read - without having to `skip_rows`.

You should be able to adapt this to your situation.

Comment: Got it. It saves an incredible quantity of time! It worked very well thank you